# Вопрос по поводу кавычек

Tags: php, sql

Вот пример кода:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $table SET 
        category     = '".$_POST['new_dish_category']."', 
        name_of_dish = '".$_POST["new_dish_name"]."',           
        discription  = '".$_POST["new_dish_discription"]."', 
        weight       = '".$_POST["new_dish_weight"]."', 
        price        = '".$_POST["new_dish_price"]."'";
```

Вопрос: почему кавычки расставлены именно таким образ, никак не могу понять? Первые двойные еще понятно, одинарные для sql, а дальше и зачем конкатенация? 
Ведь переменные можно выводить в строке и просто так, типа "тру-ля-ля $my ла-ла-ла". Объясните, пожалуйста, подробнее.

Comment: привет sql injection

Comment: а кавычки нужны, т.к. в запросе sql значение переменной должно быть в кавычках. Кроме этого названия таблицы и колонок должны быть в косых кавычках, но это уже не обязательно.

Comment: Скорее всего двойные кавычки нужны что бы внутри можно было использовать одинарные для значений без экранирование, конкатенация скорее всего использована т.к. Автор либо не знал как разместить массив с индексом внутри двойных кавычек, либо использовал конкатенацию для наглядности. Но учитывая что двойные кавычки используются даже для индексов массива, автор просто любит двойные кавычки и пытаться понять логику бессмысленно. Такие запросы лучше переписывать с использованием припарки.

Comment: В ваших "тру-ля-ля $my ла-ла-ла" надо переменную вручную писать. IDE её не подсветит для автокомплита. Не так написали и привет ошибки, которые чёрт его знает где искать. А ошибки глупые будут, что вместо `$my` вы написали `$ny` ...... а так и видно отдельно переменную и строку и автокомплит работает. Страшновато выглядит, но тем не менее.... Хотя все эти строки можно по разному записать, например через `sprintf` и тогда красивее будет........а вообще в запросах сейчас давно используют подготовленные переменные...Так что такое сложно получить в нынешние времена

Comment: Если Вам не сложно, не могли бы вы на данном примере показать как было бы правильнее написать (современнее)? @Алексей Шиманский